# varchar(max) is truncating the string when set in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar, truncate

I'm trying to print a  dynamic query but what's happening is while printing the query the characters are getting truncated.

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = cast('select*from.................length is huge' as varchar(max))
print @sql
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by truncating to be exact. Did you count the Letter it print and how many are left out? Why are you Casting when you declare the @sql as `varchar(max)` only. Not sure but casting is not required and maybe have varchar length limit within.

Comment: [Display more than 8000 characters (SQL Spackle)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/72129/)

Comment: `PRINT` will only show a maximum of 8000 chars, the variable still has the full content. Try `PRINT LEN(@sql)` for example.

Comment: what you exactly want, only print to query or want to run this dynamic query ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL function `PRINT` will only show a maximum of 8000 char, the variable still has the full content. Try running this:

```
PRINT LEN(@sql)
```

You should see a much larger number.